# How to avoid selecting textbox value when press Enter?

Tags: c#, windows, enter

```
Control nextControl;
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{     
    nextControl = GetNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift);
    if (nextControl == null)
    {
        nextControl = GetNextControl(null, true);
    }
    nextControl.Focus();               
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
 }
```

I have this code to act ENTER Key as TAB but when I press Enter key it is selecting textbox value as in image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the TextBox to select nothing

```
Control nextControl;

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{     
    nextControl = GetNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift);
    if (nextControl == null)
    {
        nextControl = GetNextControl(null, true);
    }
    nextControl.Focus();

    TextBox box = nextControl as TextBox;
    if (box != null)
        box.Select(box.Text.Length, 0);

    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: Cursor focuses at start of textbox value .Can it be at the end of textbox value?

Comment: @Vampire Sure, edited the sample. Just tell it to select 0 characters at the end of the string